# Как отследить изменение в объекте?

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты

Как в `javascript` можно отследить изменение свойства объекта и при изменении вызвать `callBack`?
Например: `obj.prop = true;` 
При изменении `obj.prop` на `false` должна вызываться функция `next()`

Comment: Можно почитать про [observer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe)

Comment: посмотри мой вариант, думаю все встанет на свои места

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Вариант через `Proxy` c `get` и `set`

Работает с вложенными объектами, а так же срабатывает `get` при удалении свойств объекта или когда происходит переход во вложенный объект. В примере легко понять что и где меняется, а так же обрабатывать изменения так как вам необходимо (вместо `console.log`).

### Пример

```js
let obj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  items: {
    firstProperty: 1,
    secondProperty: 2
  }
};

let proxied = new Proxy(obj, {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    console.log({
      type: "get",
      target,
      prop
    });
    return Reflect.get(target, prop);
  },
  set: function(target, prop, value) {
    console.log({
      type: "set",
      target,
      prop,
      value
    });
    return Reflect.set(target, prop, value);
  }
});

proxied.items.firstProperty = 3;
//{ type: 'get', target: { foo: 1,bar: 2, items: { firstProperty: 1, secondProperty: 2 } }, prop: 'items' }
//{ type: 'set', target: { foo: 1, bar: 2, items: { firstProperty: 3, secondProperty: 2 } }, prop: 'bar',  value: 2 }

proxied.bar = 2;
//{ type: 'set', target: { foo: 1, bar: 2 }, prop: 'bar', value: 2 }

proxied.asd = 3;
//{ type: 'set', target: { foo: 1, bar: 2 }, prop: 'asd', value: 3 }

proxied.foo;
//{ type: 'get', target: { foo: 1, bar: 2, asd: 3 }, prop: 'foo' }

proxied.foo = 3;
//{ type: 'set', target: { foo: 1, bar: 2, asd: 3 }, prop: 'foo', value: 3 }

delete proxied.foo;
//{ type: 'get', target: { bar: 2, asd: 3 }, prop: Symbol(util.inspect.custom) } ...

console.log(obj);
```

`object.watch` и `object.observe` являются устаревшими или экспериментальными  и не такими гибкими на данный момент.

Answer (score 3):

**1 вариант**: *использовать сеттер/геттер*

```
const obj = {
   _prop: false,
   get prop() { return this._prop }
   set prop(value) {
      // тут можно еще что-то вызвать
      this._prop = value
   }
}
```

**2 вариант**: *использовать [`proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)*

```
const handler = {
  set: function(obj, prop, value) {
    if(prop === 'prop') {
      console.log('prop was changed');
    }
    // Стандартное сохранение значения
    obj[prop] = value;
  }
};

const test = new Proxy({prop: true}, handler);

test.prop = false;
test.prop = true;
```

**3 вариант**: *[`object observe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) ( эксперимент `es7` )*

```
const obj = {prop: true};

Object.observe(obj, function(changes) {
  if(changes[0].name === 'prop') {
    console.log('prop was changed');
  }
});

obj.prop = false;
```

**4 вариант**: *просто написать функцию, в которой это св-во меняется и использовать только ее*

```
function changeObjProp (obj, value, callback) {
  obj.prop = value;
  return callback();
}

const test = {prop: false}
changeObjProp(test, true, () => console.log('prop was changed'));
```

Comment: Забыл сказать, что объект встроенный)) А 3й вариант подойдёт для встроенного объекта?

Comment: @AlexeyZolotov, что значит встроенный? Опишите лучше что именно вам нужно, возможно есть другое решение

Comment: Есть объект speechSynthesis (api для tts), у него свойство speaking меняется с false на true при воспроизведении текста в речь и наоборот при остановке.. нужно понять, когда это происходит

Comment: @AlexeyZolotov, скорее всего у него есть событие старта и остановки, на которые нужно подписаться

Comment: есть событие onend, только оно не пашет в последней версии chrome даже..

Comment: тот же прокси можете использовать с любым объектом